# Xcode compiles with simulator, but wont with real device

Tags: xcode

Im trying to load my app to my iPhone 5.0 and I get 15 errors, all having to do with architecture armv7 missing files and undefined symbols. I have xcode 4.2.1 and the errors look like this:

```
> ld: warning: ignoring file    
> /Users/kylebeard/Xcode/Construction/Foundation.framework/Foundation,
> missing required architecture armv7 in file Undefined symbols for
> architecture armv7:   "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
>       -[ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewDidUnload] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewWillAppear:] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewDidAppear:] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewWillDisappear:] in ViewController.o
>       -[ViewController viewDidDisappear:] in ViewController.o
>       ...   "_objc_setProperty", referenced from:
>       -[AppDelegate setWindow:] in AppDelegate.o
>       -[AppDelegate setViewController:] in AppDelegate.o   "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
>       _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
>       _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o   "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o
>          "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
>     "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o   "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
>       _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
>       _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o   "_objc_storeStrong", referenced from:
>       -[AppDelegate .cxx_destruct] in AppDelegate.o
>       -[ViewController .cxx_destruct] in ViewController.o   "_objc_retain", referenced from:
>    
>      "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
>      "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o   "_NSStringFromClass", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o   "_objc_release", referenced from:
>       _main in main.o   "_objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue", referenced from:
>       
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
>       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is `missing architecture armv7` as you say, so make sure `armv7` is added to the Architectures section of your build settings in Xcode, and try recompiling then. Also, check it's not being overridden to `i386` in any of your Targets.

Comment: Standard armv7 is added(ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT) and i386 is not overridden anywhere. I also applied yes to the build active architecture in both targets and project. I still get errors

Comment: Oh. You'll want to set Build Active Architecture Only to no.

Comment: Im switched them back and nothing changed. Ive read on other websites about how if you started a project and then updated xcode, it could cause problems. I started with 4.1 and upgraded to 4.2 halfway through so maybe there could be something wrong there. Im considering creating a new project and copying all of my code into that new project to keep it uniform

Comment: That would be helpful since default build settings on new Xcode builds for both `armv6` and `armv7` (assuming you make a Cocoa Touch project). If it still doesn't work then, you may have a corrupt `iOS SDK` and would need to remove/redownload Xcode.